# Prove that if $a_n>0$ and $\sum a_{n}$ converges, then $ \sum \frac{1}{a_{n}}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Prove that if $a_n>0$ for every $n$ and $\sum a_{n}$ converges, then $ \sum \frac{1}{a_{n}}$ diverges.

As $\sum a_{n}$ converges, $a_{n}$ converges to $0$.  Therefore $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{a_{n}} \neq 0$ so therefore $ \sum \frac{1}{a_{n}}$ diverges.

I don't know how to show that if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_{n} = 0$ then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{a_{n}} \neq 0$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proving $\sum \frac{1}{A_n}$ is divergent if $\sum A_n $ is convergent](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045047/proving-sum-frac1a-n-is-divergent-if-sum-a-n-is-convergent)

Comment: Mines the original, that is the duplicate :D :P

Comment: Right. And if the other gets reopened, that should be closed as a duplicate of this. Priority can be overridden with a good reason, but the best answer is here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume that every $a_n$ is nonzero (otherwise the problem makes no sense) and, for every $n$, consider $b_n=1/a_n$. If the series $\sum\limits_na_n$ converges then $a_n\to0$ hence $|a_n|\leqslant1$ for every $n$ large enough hence $\left|b_n\right|\geqslant1$ for every $n$ large enough hence $b_n$ does not converge to $0$ hence the series $\sum\limits_nb_n$ does not converge.

This does not use the assumption that every $a_n$ is positive, only that every $a_n$ is nonzero.

Comment: Can we write when an = 0 for some n then clearly ∑bn diverges as bn is undefined when an=0 ?

Comment: ...Then bn is undefined for some n hence the series ∑bn is undefined and as such, it neither diverges nor converges, it simply does not exist.